# Python speed differences

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I was recently trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams/) on Hackerrank. I ended up with the following solution which gives the right answer within the given time limit:

```
from collections import Counter
lisa=[]
for each in range(input()):
    current=raw_input()
    count=0
    lookup_dict={}
    i=0
    for i in range(len(current)):
        for j in range(i,len(current)):
            sub_string=current[i:j+1]
            sub_string=''.join(sorted(sub_string))
            if sub_string in lookup_dict.keys():
                lookup_dict[sub_string]+=1
            else:
                lookup_dict[sub_string]=1

    for k in lookup_dict.values():
        count+=k*(k-1)/2
    print count
```

My problem is that the solution provided by them (reproduced below) is significantly faster than the one I wrote even though the complexity and method used is same.

```
from collections import *
for i in range(input()):
    s = raw_input()
    check = defaultdict(int)
    l = len(s)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i+1,l+1):
            sub = list(s[i:j])
            sub.sort()
            sub = "".join(sub)
            check[sub]+=1
    sum = 0
    for i in check:
        n = check[i]
        sum += (n*(n-1))/2
    print sum
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the `defaultdict` method, but can't figure out why?

Comment: My guess would be that the problem is that you are iterating through the keys in `if sub_string in lookup_dict.keys()`, thing that you do not need to do in the latter example because you are using a `defaultdict`

Comment: you could try to replace only the `defaultdict` part and check the time taken again, also you are computing `len(current)` on each loop, the second example cache the value as it do not change

Comment: To expand on @cnluzon's comment, try replacing `lookup_dict.keys()` with just `lookup_dict` and see how that affects your speed.

Comment: Also not a big speed difference but you should use `from collections import defaultdict`, it's more Pythonic.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that increased the speed. Almost ten times for the largest test case. But again, why?

Comment: @ClockSlave I believe `.keys()` will immediately generate a full list while checking `in dict` checks values one by one.

Comment: I suspect that `keys()` is O(n) time, where N is the number of elements in the dict. `x in dict` is O(1) time, so it tends to have superior performance for large dictionaries.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan you're incorrect about the behavior of `in dict`, that will not check the keys 1 by 1, it will hash what you're searching for and look it up in the table, an O(1) operation.

Comment: @iobender Times like this remind me I should figure out what hashing actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x , `dict.keys()` returns a list, and in your first solution, you are actually doing -

```
if sub_string in lookup_dict.keys()
```

This would be an O(n) operation (n being the size of the dictonary - `lookup_dict`) , since `.keys()` actually returns a list and containment check in list are O(n) and also most probably there is the added cost of having to create the list.

Whereas in the second approach, you do not have any such check, rather defaultdict is handling setting the default value automatically for you, and that may be one of the reasons why your first solution is significantly slower than the second (Given that you do the `dict.keys()` lookup in the innermost loop , so that lookup happens that many times).

---

Example showing `dict.keys()` returning list -

```
>>> d = {1:2,3:4,5:6,7:8}
>>> d.keys()
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Besides O(N) for list lookup there's O(M) for memory alloc, where M - total number of unique keys. So in worst case its pretty close to O(N²)

Answer (score 1):

Talking about `defaultdict`: its optimized a bit compared to plain key check. I.e.:

```
x = defaultdict(int)
for i in xrange(...):
    x[i] += 1
```

performs ~50% faster than

```
x = {}
for i in xrange(...):
    if i in x:
         x[i] +=1
    else:
        x[1] = 1
```

if case of **all** keys missing.

But the main case is that calling `dict.keys()` in py2 actually creates a list. So checking `key in dict.keys()` need allocate memory for list first, then populate it with actual key values, and after that check your key against it. What is worst, right after that this list should be cleaned by garbage collector, and in next `for` step you'll do the same, except more memory will be allocated for that list. So, that's actually kill performance in your example.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest someplace from where I can read more on the architecture of the language?

Comment: May sound pretty obvious, but https://docs.python.org/ is nice way to go, especially when you know what to look for.

For entry level uhm... Mark Lutz should do the trick, but reading last editions can be pain in ass, as its really detailed.

For a bit higher level - when you actually can write things, but not always know why things works that way - take a look at Julien Danjou's "Hackers guide to Python" and Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho. Last one turned out surprisingly cool.
And 1 more thing: I strongly recommend iPython with its magic %timeit - will save you a lot of time )